# Adding <div> With jQuery - Weird Click Behavior

Tags: jquery, html, click, append

I'm having some weird behavior with `appendTo()` in jQuery.

This is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#mydiv").click(function () {
        $(this).append('<div class="well">Added div</div>' );
        $(this).appendTo(div.last);
    });
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="last">
    <center><a id="mydiv"><h3>New List</h3></a></center>
</div>
```

Obviously, when I click the "New List" link, I get a new `<div>` added to `<div id="last">`. It looks like this:

[image: Picture of divs]

And if I keeping clicking `New List`, I get more and more `<div>`s. This is fine. However, when I click one of the newly-create `<div>`s, it also adds one. (WHen I click the "added div" grey space). I;m going to be putting textboxes in these new `<div>`s, and I don't want it adding more and more `<div>`s when the user clicks to type.

What can I do to make it so new `<div>`s are created *only* when I click the "New List" link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.after()` instead of `.append()`. At the moment, your new divs are being added within your a tag.

Comment: Thanks so much! You saved the day! 11 minutes until I'm allowed to accept your answer.

Comment: No problem, easy to get them muddled up.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `append()` adds a **child**, not a **sibling**. So the click refers to the whole container **myDiv** which contains all the added divs and remains clickable.
Use `after()` to add a sibling.